# How to add security permissions in build.xml using Ant Web Start

Tags: java, ant, java-web-start, jnlp

I am not very familiar with java build tools such as Ant. We have an old java web start application and now with the [new security requirements for RIAs](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) I have to add a security tag to my build.xml But I can't figure out how to do it. I am using ant deploy to build my app. And I am also using ant-jnlp-war (I really can't figure out where this ant-jnlp-war is used) The relevant part of my build.xml is as the following:

```
<target name="pack" depends="buildinfo,dist,sign">
    <jw:jnlpwar
        tofile="${war}/lmc.war"
        title="Company Management Console"
        vendor="Company Teknoloji"
        codebase="dummy"
        signStorepass="secret"
        signAlias="labris">
            <jw:description>Company Management Console</jw:description>
            <jw:description kind="short">LMC</jw:description>
            <jw:shortcut desktop="true" menu="true" submenu="Company Management Console"/>
            <jw:j2se minVersion="1.5" args="-Xmx128M" />
            <lib dir="${dist}/lib">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                <exclude name="client.jar"/>
            </lib>
            <lib dir="${dist}/modules">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            </lib>
            <jw:application mainclass="com.idealteknoloji.lmc.client.ClientManager" jar="${dist}/lib/client.jar"/>
    </jw:jnlpwar>
    <exec executable="./make-client-packages"/>
</target>
```

How and where can I add the security attribute as sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

Let's clarify...

[Ant-jnlp-war](http://ant-jnlp-war.sourceforge.net/) just create war which allow you to distribute your application to clients and contains your jar that means that you **should have jar before call ant-jnlp-war**.

[New security requirements for RIA](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) related to jar because you need to specify in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF from which site application could be distributed:

> **Manifest Attributes**
>
> 1. Permissions – Introduced in 7u25, and required as of 7u51. Indicates if the RIA should run within the sandbox or require full-permissions.
> 2. Codebase – Introduced in 7u25 and optional/encouraged as of 7u51. Points to the known location of the hosted code (e.g. intranet.example.com).

As we clarify **you don't need to change ant-jnlp-war** you just need to have correct MANIFEST.MF within your jar.

Here you have two options:

1. use Ant task to create MANIFEST.MF [like](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) and configure it, [example](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html):

   ```
     <jar destfile="test.jar" basedir=".">
         <include name="build"/>
         <manifest>
             <attribute name="Permissions" value="sandbox">
             <attribute name="Codebase" value="example.com">
         </manifest>
     </jar>
   ```
2. create by hand MANIFEST.MF and put to your jar under folder META-INF

   ```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Created-By: 1.7.0_51
   Permissions: sandbox
   Codebase: www.java.com
   ```